# How to create a custom route with query params in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I would like to create custom routes in my Wp website using two query params, like these:
`http://www.mywebsite.com/apin/?code=CODE&f=getInfo` or `http://www.mywebsite.com/apin/?code=CODE&f=getCategories`

I have created a custom plugin with these methods:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'getMovieInfo' );


function getMovieInfo() {
    register_rest_route( 'apin', '/?token=(?P<token>[a-f0-9]+)&f=getInfoApp', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_movie_info',
        )
    );
}


function get_movie_info($datas) {
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'movies'));
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        $fields = get_fields($post->ID);
        $code = $fields['movie_code'];
        if ($code === $datas['movie_code']) {
            $data=[];
            $data['movie_title'] = $post->post_title;
            $data['movie_description'] = $fields['movie_description'];
            $data['movie_categories'] = $fields['movie_categories'];
            $data['movie_image'] = $fields['movie_image']['url'];
            return $data;
        } else {
            return "No matching results";
        }   
    }
}
```

However I don't know how to properly use the namespace and how to create different methods for different query params (I need to retrieve a particular movie using its code and return different results of its field according to the '&f=METHOD', like 'getInfo' or 'getCategories')

Comment: The route itself shouldn't contain the query string. Just create the base route (something like  `/your-endpoint`). Then when it's called, get the query parameters ($_GET['param-name']) and do what you need to do depending on them.

Comment: Okay, but what should I use as namespace and as route in this case?